# When should we improve a suggested edit, rather than reject it?

Tags: discussion

There is a [suggested edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2318) in the queue right now for [Drupal Commerce - Multiple Shipping](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31868/drupal-commerce-multiple-shipping).

The title change can be seen as an improvement, but the suggested edit removes [drupal-commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce), which I think is totally the wrong.

Have people been improving these types of suggested edits, or rejecting them?

My main reason for considering the rejection, is because I always use a custom reason for the rejection, and would mention that removing the tags like this should not be done.

Another way to ask this is, which is better: improving the edit to make the site better to rejecting the edit so the editor knows that retags like this are bad?

Comment: According to the folks on Meta SO (can't find a reference right now but I've seen this more than once), if any part of an edit is invalid then the whole edit should be rejected as invalid. Since removing the drupal-commerce tag was clearly incorrect (the question specifically mentions Commerce several times), the right thing to do is to reject the whole edit

Comment: It depends from how much of the edit is correct. If the proposed edit changes 5 parts of the post, and only one change is not correct, I would not reject the proposed edit; I would rather correct the part that is not correct (which means I improve the edit). I would reject a proposed edit that changes a single punctuation mark, when there are other things to change, or a proposed edit done from a user who changes the question's title for the third time in row.

Answer (score 1):

The question being asked is, "Is this even possible with current modules for Drupal Commerce?" which leads me to think the question is not about the Drupal Commerce module, for which [drupal-commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce) is thought. If the tag changes are not correct, then look at the rest of the edit being done. Is it useful? If it is useful, improve the suggested edit by changing back the tags as they were.

I generally approve the suggested edit, if it is mostly correct; if there is something that I don't think was correctly changed, then I improve the suggested edit by changing that part.

If you reject the edit just to be able to say to the user the tags should not have been edited, consider the second alternative:

- Improve the edit, changing back the tags as they were.
- Write a comment for the user, starting it with a @-reference to the user who edited it (in this case, *@espero*).

As far as I recall, @-references work also for who edits a post; once you approve/improve the suggested edit, the user who suggested the edit becomes one of the users who edited the post.

If there are users who keep doing the same mistake in the suggested edits (e.g. systematically replacing a tag with another one), you already wrote a comment saying that is not right to do that (using a @-reference after improving one of your edits), and they keep doing the same type of edits, then you can:

- Improve all the edits done from that user, to leave the good part, and remove the bad part of the edit
- Start rejecting the edits done from that user

When you reject enough suggested edits from that user, that user will not be able to suggest edits for 7 days. At that point, the user would notice suggested edits are not possible anymore, and (possibly) ask a question on the meta site, to which you can explain why the suggested edits have been rejected.
Whenever choosing one option, or the other one, it is up to you. Consider that you could also leave the decision to somebody else, if you aren't comfortable with either the options.

The reason I am not suggesting to use the rejecting reason is that the rejecting reason is not immediately visible to the user, and it is probable the user doing a wrong edit will not see it. If I look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/199/kiamlaluno?tab=activity&sort=suggestions, all I see is this.

[image: screenshot]

Until I don't click on the "suggested edit" link, I don't see if my suggested edit was accepted, or rejected. I still have to go looking for that information; I am not given any notification about that.

With this I am not saying that rejecting a suggested edit should not done. If the edit contained something good, and you want to teach the user, you can use the suggestion I made here.

See also [What to do with suggested edits that add extra information to an answer](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/887/what-to-do-with-suggested-edits-that-add-extra-information-to-an-answer).